# Kafka Consumer is not able to deserialize timewindowed key which has start and end time

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have one Kafka Streams app (V 2.1.1) which produces record and put into output topic in key value format.

key is windowed time serde where I am expecting key and handle to window start/end time.

Example -

```
.to(kafkaOutPutTopic, Produced.with(windowedSerde, jsonSerde));
```

Sample - [KEY@1551807076000/1551807077000]
where KEY is key, start time - 1551807076000 and end time - 1551807077000

Where WindowedSerde is

```
StringSerializer stringSerializer = new StringSerializer();

final TimeWindowedSerializer<String> windowedSerializer = new TimeWindowedSerializer(stringSerializer);

final TimeWindowedDeserializer<String> windowedDeSerializer = new TimeWindowedDeserializer();

final Serde<Windowed<String>> windowedSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(windowedSerializer, windowedDeSerializer);
```

There is one more component called kafka consumer which tries to consume message from topic and get hold of key and window start/end time by DeSerializering with custom class.

kafka property:

```
kafkaConsumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, TimeWindowedDeserializer.class.getName());
```

I am using TimeWindowedDeserializer.java  from attached link - https://gist.github.com/nfo/eaf350afb5667a3516593da4d48e757a

but enable to get window end time and consumer fails to consume it due to deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7110

It's fixed in 2.2.0, that allows you pass the window size into the constructor or `TimeWindows`.

Note, that neither the window end-timestamp, nor the window size are store in the data. This is a storage optimization, because for `TimeWindows` the size is the same for all windows, and thus, the end-timestamp can be computed based on start-timestamp plus window size.

Comment: Thank you,Similler to your suggestion I have implemented end time based on window start time + window size.